# LinkedIn login API gives Access Forbidden 403 in step 3

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

So I have been following the [tutorial](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) to set up a LinkedIn login for my website.

I am able to do first two steps with ease and I get the authorization code.

Now I have to send HTTP POST and get JSON response to complete my LinkedIn API. I used following [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6609181) to do same but I am getting an error.

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.linkedin.com): failed to open
>   stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\LinkedIn\index.php on line 22 bool(false)

Can Anyone tell me what am I possibly doing wrong or alternative workaround?

Comment: can you updated your Question With Your code ??

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar : i have linked code i have used , click 'method'. i have used exact same code insttead of their sample data in array i used my linked spefic data.

Comment: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-login-with-linkedin-oauth2-in-php-and-mysql_3858.html    ...Try This ..

Comment: Thankyou @RïshïKêshKümar but i have googled them and was trying to code it up from official doc without being dependent on code provided by 3rd parties

Answer (score 0):

2 Years back i worked on linkedin login but it didn't work for me too.
I suggest instead using OAuth login try with javascript SDK.
[linkedin login SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin)

http to https could also the reason for access forbidden because OAuth hits a server to server request which is basically http to https.

Hope this will help.